# C# throws errors on ToString() method

Tags: c#

I have been trying to fix this error on ToString method, but don't know what's the problem. It's says "return type must be string"

```
public override void ToString()
 {
        return ("{0,-20}  {1,-15}  {2,-10} {3,-10}  {4,-10}", this.name, this.number, String.Format("{0:c}", this.rate), String.Format("{0:00}", this.hours), String.Format("{0:00}", this.gross));
 }
```

Comment: The method's current return type is `void`, which you should change to `string`. You're then going to need to adjust what you're returning, because currently you're returning a tuple. It looks like these are the parameters for a `string.Format` call, but you're missing the actual function.

Comment: Also, instead of commas use the `+` sign to make it a string.

Comment: It looks like he wants to use string.format with that params

Comment: Do you know what a "return type" is?  Because if you don't, then you're not going to be able to solve this problem. Perhaps your question should be "what is a return type?"

Comment: @EricLippert the return type was a string

Comment: @michaelchu: Do you know what the return type *in the function header* is?  Put another way: you typed "void".  Why did you type the word "void"?  What did you think that meant, and why?  Everything in a C# program has a meaning; you should understand the meaning *before* you type it.

Comment: I am pretty sure VS auto complete would never fill in an incorrect header like that either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify the return type as part of your method signature. The method is currently set to `void` (which means it doesn't return a value), and you should change this to `string`:

```
public override string ToString()
```

Additionally, it appears you're using a format string, but you're missing the `string.Format` method call, which would look something like:

```
return string.Format("{0,-20}  {1,-15}  {2,-10} {3,-10}  {4,-10}",
    this.name,
    this.number,
    string.Format("{0:c}", this.rate),
    string.Format("{0:00}", this.hours),
    string.Format("{0:00}", this.gross));
```

Comment: I tried that now it throws an error on the return line , "cannot implicitly convert type "

Comment: I updated the answer for that as well (at least the best I can, since you haven't provided us with the actual types of `rate`, `hours`, or `gross`)

Comment: I know it may be pedantic, but considering the experience of the OP it is worth mentioning, that `void` functions do return. They just don't return a value.

Comment: @schulmaster: Indeed. It would be nice if C# had a return type that was "never" -- that is, a method which does not return at all. Such a method could only go into an infinite loop, or throw. Such a method would be signature compatible with a delegate type regardless of the delegate's return type.

Comment: @EricLippert While you're under the hood, might as well throw in a `perhaps` return type to really spice things up.

Comment: @schulmaster: Under what circumstances would a perhaps type have a different behavior than a standard return?  Existing return types (including void) are already able to never return and the system handles it as-is.  The `never` return type lets you do new stuff.  In addition to the signature compatibility change Eric mentions, his proposal also impacts the reachability analysis.  For example, you could use `ExceptionFactory.Throw()` instead of `throw ExceptionFactory.Make()` and the compiler would still know that further code is unreachable.